# Can't connect to my Amazon Web Services RDS instance from my application: internal server error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am able to connect to my RDS instance from the terminal(SSH), however, connecting from my application had been returning error code 500: Internal Server Error.

I have configured my security group to be the security group that i am using for the EC2 instance.

In my security group, I have created rule for mysql connection via port 3306, from any IP (0.0.0.0/0)

Attached is the image of my security group and the RDS instance.

I have tried many suggestion from the answers posted here on stackoverflow.

```html
<?php
echo "OK before connection";

$dsn = 'mysql:host=klaudcelet-db.cwjchxqjfoaj.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com;port=3306;dbname=providers';
$username = 'klaudcelet';
$password= '12345678';

//not the real password
$link = mysqli_connect('klaudcelet-db.cwjchxqjfoaj.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com', 'klaudcelet', '12345678', 'providers', 3306);

echo "First OK";


$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);


echo 'OK';
```

[My security group rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zng4L.png)

[rds configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Jnc.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide what kind of application do you use? And maybe it can be better if you share your connection code block.

Comment: I have added the code that i use for connecting

Comment: Are you connecting both with mysqli_connect and PDO?

Comment: Yes, I am testing both of them. I am using PDO in my application but according to suggestions from some similar issue via stackoverflow, I added mysqli for testing.

Comment: Solved. I created another rule for mysql in the security group, and I added only my IP. So, i have 2 rules for MySQL.